# Result from py2neo is different with Neo4j browser, query include special characters

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

The result I got by querying via Neo4j browser

```
MATCH (_:AAA) WHERE _.name =  "abc\\\'_dbe\\\'_abc" RETURN _

Return The node I want
```

is different with I queried via py2neo as follows:

```py
result = graph.run("""
MATCH (_:AAA) WHERE _.name =  "abc\\\'_dbe\\\'_abc" RETURN _
""")

Return No Data
```

Does anybody has the situation with me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share what you get with Neo4j Browser and what you get with py2neo?

Comment: I got No data from py2neo. The node I need in Neo4j Browser.

Answer (score 1):

Backslashes are tricky. Some of those are going to be swallowed by Python itself, so I recommend using a raw string (`r"""..."""`) for your query instead.

Comment: Tips: If we use format to combine the raw string and normal string, we need to .encode('unicode-escape').decode() to encode and decode the normal string first.